# HttpClient PostAsycn Always returns 404 Not Found but controller works with Postman and Javascript application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Post Web Api Method in a controller and it's already working, I've been testing the method sending file from postman and a my own web application and it works but now I'm trying to send file from console application using Httpclient but always get 404.

Controller Method

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        FileServerConfig config = FileServerConfiguration.ObtenerConfiguracion(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);

        var path = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

            foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
            {
                IFileServerWrapper _cliente = FileServerConfiguration.CrearCliente(config);
                var name = stream.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\", "");
                var fileUploaded = await _cliente.FileUpload(path, await stream.ReadAsStreamAsync(), name, false);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (HttpException httpex)
        {
            if (httpex.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                return InternalServerError(httpex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

    }
```

Console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Software\itextTifftoPDF.rar";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            // Make sure to change API address
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:80/FileServerAPI/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // Add first file content 
            var fileContent1 = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
            fileContent1.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = "itextTifftoPDF.rar"
            };

            content.Add(fileContent1);

            // Make a call to Web API
            var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/FileServerAPI/api/File", content).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a sniffer (e.g. Wireshark') to capture the actual URL being used.to post to. There you will probably see what is wrong.

Comment: thanks @JohanDonne, Wireshark couldn't help me but I foud Microsoft Message Analyzer to capture local traffic and it helped me a lot to find the problem, now my problem is solved.

Answer (score -3):

Finally I found a solution. the code is ugly because it was made just to be sure it works but I'll hope it may help others with the same problem.

```
string filePath = @"C:\temp\webdavtest.txt";
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (MultipartFormDataContent content =
                             new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(
                      filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamContent streamConent =
                                        new StreamContent(stream))
                    {
                        content.Add(
                        streamConent, "webdavtest.txt", "webdavtest.txt");
                        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:3983/api/File?path=/nivel5/", content);
                        return result.StatusCode.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer.  What did you do here to solve the problem (without having to scour your code)?